# Automate a reoccuring manual task (generate order number based on name) in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm currently working on a EpiServer project where we use the ContentType attribute to set the DisplayName and Order of the blocks. The Order is based on the name of the block. Here's an example:

```
[ContentType(
    DisplayName = "My First Block",
    Order = 133536,
    GUID = "0f02e38a-a6e2-4333-9bd1-c61cf573d8d3",
    Description = "Just an example block.",
    GroupName = "Blocks.Content"
    )]
public class MyFirstBlock : BaseBlock
{
}
```

Apparently EpiServer can't sort the blocks alphabetically so we generate the order based on the DisplayName as a work around. A formula was invented to determine the order. One colleague has written a JavaScript function that can be used to generate the order number:

```
function getEPiOrderNumber(value) {
    var alphabeticalIndex = function (character) {
        return character.toLowerCase().charCodeAt() - 96;
    };

    var firstSection = alphabeticalIndex(value[0]);
    var secondSection = alphabeticalIndex(value[1]) + 10;
    var thirdSection = alphabeticalIndex(value[2]) + 100;

    return `${firstSection}${secondSection}${thirdSection}`;
}
```

This function can be executed in the console of a browser. Better than having to calculate the order by hand, but this requires that I switch to a browser, open the console, paste this code and execute it and finally copy the result and paste it in the model I'm working on.

I figured it would be much more convenient to be able to do generate the order number from within VS. I have been looking into using Visual Studio Extensions but can't really find anything that is to my liking.

The most optimal solution would be to be able to select the (part of the) DisplayName, right click and select a new command from the context menu that will generate the order and paste it at the correct location. Or place it on the clip board so I can easily paste it in the right location myself. A pop-up displaying the order would be fine as well.

Is this even possible?

Another option could be a new command in one of the toolbar menu's, say Tools, that would display a small window where I can enter/ paste the text and to have it generate the order that I can then paste in the code.

I have figured out how to add an Custom Command to the Tools menu and how I could generate the code and display it, but how can I enter the text? Or is it maybe possible to retrieve selected text from the editor window? That would solve my problem as well.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

PS. I'm not too happy with the title of this question so I'm open to suggestions if anyone can think of a title that better describes my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve selected text from Visual Studio editor window with following code.

```
        DTE dte = (DTE)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));

        string text = "";

        if (dte.ActiveDocument != null)
        {
            var selection = (TextSelection)dte.ActiveDocument.Selection;
            text = selection.Text;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Wendy, that helped me a great deal! I now have a working VS Extension that Takes the selected text, turns that into an order number and places the order number on the clipboard. The command is added to the Tools menu, if I could get it in the shortcut menu that would be close to perfect.

Comment: @elloco999 You could set a shortcut for your custom command. Please refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138531.aspx

Comment: I've now got it working with a shortcut and also managed to find replace the old order number with the new one. The regex I use to find the order number could use a little work but it does the job. Thank you very much for pushing me in the right direction!